# MapStruct 1.3.0.Beta2 passing DTO to qualifiedByName method

Tags: spring-boot, mapping, dto, mapstruct

I'm using `MapStruct 1.3.0 Beta2` and I would like to pass the `DTO` I'm mapping inside a `qualifiedByName` method, for Example:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {

  @Mapping(target = "id", qualifiedByName = "test")
  UserDTO entityToUser(User entity);

  @Named("test")
  default Integer test(UserDTO userDto) {
    return userDto.getId();
  }
}
```

Clearly I have to do more complex operation this is just an example. Is there a way to do this??

Thank you

Comment: There's also the 1.3.0.Final and the 1.4.0.CR1 (with 1.4.0.Final in the making)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved as follows:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {

  UserDTO entityToUser(User entity);

  @AfterMapping
  default void test(User entity, @MappingTarget UserDTO userDto) {
      // some operations
  }
}
```

hope helps.